# _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData) Error: Realloc() pointer

Tags: c, pointers, realloc, singly-linked-list

I got the _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData) Message when compiling my Code in VS2012 (C).

I realized I was trying to use the `realloc` on the pointer so when I read other posts, many suggested using `memcpy` and `const char **`. I really love to do so but I just do not know how.

First Fragment of Code: Typedef struct of the Pointer that I am using to `realloc`

```
int clientcounter = 0; //Global variable since this will be needed in other functions

typedef struct client{
    char name[254];
    int birthday;
    int landline;
    int cellphone;
    int clientnum;
    struct client *next; 
}clientdata;
```

My program reads the content of the file and stores it to these variables through Singly linked-list.

Second Fragment of Code:

```
void loading_file(clientdata curr[])
{
    clientdata *dummy[10000] = {0};
    clientdata *head;
    clientdata *tail;

    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;

    //.... Asking for roster file

    //.. memory allocation of dummy[clientcounter]

    //.... Storing data to variables

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = dummy[clientcounter];
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next=dummy[clientcounter];
    }
    tail = dummy[clientcounter];

    if (head!=NULL)
    {
        dummy[clientcounter-1] = head;
        do {
            printf("\n ::%s:: Name\n",dummy[clientcounter]->name);
            curr[clientcounter] = dummy[clientcounter];
            dummy[clientcounter] = realloc(dummy,sizeof(item*) * clientcounter); //Error appears Here
            dummy[clientcounter] = NULL;
            clientcounter++;
            dummy[clientcounter] = dummy[clientcounter-1]->next;
        }while(dummy[totalitem] != NULL);
    }
    free(dummy[totalitem-1]);
}
```

Someone told me that everytime when `clientcounter++` happens, I have to reallocate the memory so that it won't leak. My problem is, I know what causes the error (reallocating the pointer) but I do not know how to fix it.

Can anyone teach me how to fix the code?

Comment: Your `do{}` loop isn't valid (there is no `while()` condition. And I see no reason for the dummy pointer array in this code *at all*. We also have no idea what `clientdata` or `hero` is. As near as i can see you don't need *any* of the lower-logic in that snippet to load a linked list from a file, and you certainly shouldn't need `realloc()`. *What problem are you trying to solve?*

Comment: @WhozCraig My apologies. Edited

Comment: @WhozCraig So even if `clientcounter` increases, I do not need to reallocate the `dummy[clientcounter]`? If I remove the `realloc`, then I get "Acess Violation Reading location" at `dummy[clientcounter] = dummy[clientcounter-1]->next;`

Comment: What I'm saying is if all this is supposed to do is build a forward-linked list, then the pointer arrays, the reallocing, *all of it* isn't needed at all. Thus why I asked, *What problem are you trying to solve.*

Comment: @WhozCraig My program is not functioning in the linked-list part.There are multiple "sets" of data in the file (1 set = 5 variables stated in `typedef`) and my program only prints the first set then breaks. I believe the break happened in `dummy[clientcounter] = dummy[clientcounter-1]->next;` with "Acess Violation Reading location" if I do not include `realloc`

Comment: And last-time, **what problem are you trying to solve??** "Fix my code." isn't the answer; that is the Y part of an XY-problem, where the *real problem* is X, your solution is Y. Regarding what is outright-wrong in your code, you're passing `dummy` as the source-address to `realloc()`, which is **undefined behaviour**. `dummy` was never allocated on the heap, it is a stack-array of pointers. And even if it *was* a heap allocation (which it isn't) you immediately throw away anything that was returned from that invalid-realloc by the hard-assignment to NULL on the very next line.

Comment: ...continued... you're also sending `curr` into this without so much as a hint as to what its top-limit is, and I'm simply going to tell you one last time, if you're intent is to load this file, item by item, into a forward-linked list *none of this is needed*. If you want to know how to do that, I can show you. if you want to know how to load it into a dynamic pointer-array *and* a linked list, I can show you that as well. if not, I wish you the very best of luck.

Comment: @WhozCraig sorry that my questions are vague till the end. I just want to know why isn't my linked-list working.

Comment: So you *do* want to load the file into a linked list? is that correct? (and I hope you're at least beginning to realize `curr`, `dummy`, are *both* pointless if that is the case).

Comment: @WhozCraig Can you please show me how? You can send your code to my email: h1dkim17@yahoo.com .(I cannot do the chat here due to low reputation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the end-goal is to simply load a file of data into a linked list, most of the posted code is extraneous and simply not needed. Following is a *very* simple implementation of loading a data file into a forward linked list.

**What Is Needed**

The general algorithm is this:

- Read a single line from the input file.
- Parse the line into our structure members.
- If all the members properly parsed, create a new item and add it to the list.

The last step is the core of the above code, and I'll explain how it works after the code. this modified function takes the file name being processed as the only input parameter, and returns a linked list of `clientdata` items, the parsing of which **you still have to write**, so don't think you're getting all of this for free:

**The Code**

```
clientdata* load_file(const char fname[])
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "r");
    char line[512]; // suitable value

    // pp always holds the *address* of the pointer where the
    //  next node will be added to the list. notice how it first
    //  holds the address of our list-head pointer.
    clientdata *result = NULL;
    clientdata **pp = &result;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
    {
        clientdata val = {0};

        //
        // TODO: parse line into val-members using things like
        //  sscanf(), strtok(), or others, etc.
        //

        if (parsed-successfully-condition)
        {
            // allocate a new list node, copy over the data
            *pp = malloc(sizeof(**pp));
            if (*pp)
            {
                memcpy(*pp, &val, sizeof(**pp));

                // load pp with the address of the 'next' member for
                //  the node we just allocated and saved. it will be
                //  the link to the next new node if we need one
                pp = &(*pp)->next;
            }
            else
            {   // malloc() failed. not good. no sense in continuing.
                perror("Failed to allocate new node.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // required. this terminates the list.
    *pp = NULL; 
    return result;
}
```

**The Explanation**

We keep two pointers. One is the return result pointer (`result`) and is initially NULL. The other is a pointer-to-pointer, `pp`, that initially holds the *address* of our return result pointer. This is a special variable. It is a pointer-to-pointer that will always hold the address of the *next* pointer we need to set when making a new allocation. A picture speaks a thousand words. The initial configuration looks like this:

```
result = NULL;
^---- pp
```

When we insert a new node we populate whatever pointer who's address is being held in pp. The first time that address will be pointing to `result`. Note the dereference, `*pp`. So after adding a new node, then moving the address of the new node's `next` pointer in to `pp`, the picture now looks like this:

```
result --> item0
           next
pp --------^
```

And after the second insertion

```
result --> item0
           next --> item1
                    next
pp -----------------^
```

And finally one more...

```
result --> item0
           next --> item1
                    next --> item2
                             next
pp --------------------------^
```

The algorithm finishes by terminating the list. This is done by setting the pointer addressed by `pp` to NULL. Note the wording there. We are NOT setting `pp` to NULL (that would be pointless). We're setting the pointer *it addresses* to NULL.

`*pp = NULL;`

The resulting picture would finish like this:

```
result --> item0
           next --> item1
                    next --> item2
                             next --> NULL
```

In each case the insertion mantra is always the same.

- Store a new allocation in the node pointed to by `*pp`
- copy over the data to the new allocation
- store the *next* pointer to receive the next new allocation in `pp`
- loop until we finish reading the file.
- upon exiting the loop, set `*pp` to NULL, since it is the *last* `next` pointer in our chain, and should be NULL to terminate the linked list.

There are some interesting base-conditions that are worth understanding. A notable one is "What happens when the input file has **no** items? Does this still work?" Yes, indeed it does. In that case the while-loop will never add a new item, `pp` will still contain the address of `result`, and `*pp = NULL;` will (redundantly) set it to NULL. The result will be a NULL return value, exactly what you want for a linked list that is "empty".

I *strongly* suggest running this in a debugger to see how `pp`, `*pp`, and `**pp` work in this algorithm.